# IOS - PayPal SDK - Screen goes blank

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, paypal

I followed this tutorial here:https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md

In my project i have a view controller and in this view controller i have a button that triggers the code in the example, so what i have done is created PayPalViewController and used the code above.

How i open the PayPalViewController:

```
- (void)handleStep2UploadTap2:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer {

    AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    appDelegate.paypalViewController = [PayPalViewController new];


    [self presentViewController:appDelegate.paypalViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

What happens is that the screen goes blank once the button is triggered. Xcode works fine no errors no crash, why does the screen go blank?

Comment: well, i guess my questions are: 1) have you done all of the other steps it has listed  2) `PayPalPaymentViewController ` has a designed initializer by way of `initWithPayment:configuration:delegate:` and 3) what is `paypalViewController`? A subclassed UIVIewController?

Answer (score 1):

Dave from PayPal here.

@Louis-Tur asked the right questions!

Specifically, if you follow the integration instructions at https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/blob/master/docs/single_payment.md then you'll see that `appDelegate.paypalViewController = [PayPalViewController new];` is not the correct way to create the view controller.

If you need further clarification, we'll be glad to help!